# Developing and deploying SurfaceScrollViewer

Tags: wpf-controls, pixelsense

I'm having a hard time finding the correct information on this.

I've been using WPF for my applications because of the enhanced visuals you can achieve with it.  Right now my controls are basic WPF controls (ListView, ComboBox, etc.) and are scrolled using the basic Windows methods (Scrollbar, Scroll buttons), which is not touchscreen friendly (I use Elo touchscreens, which are NOT multi-touch, and only emulate a mouse click on touch/selection).

I want to use the [SurfaceScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.surfacescrollviewer.aspx) control (Or something similar) because it does exactly what I need, to get touch type scrolling without having to use the old Windows scrollbars (Thanks to the iPhone, people are now expecting this in every GUI they encounter).

So, can I use the SurfaceScrollViewer in an application deployed to a system that IS NOT Surface hardware ($15k... ouch)?  If not, is MS going to do provide a control that Windows developers can use on a regular Windows (XP, Vista, 7) platform without having to use specialized hardware?  If not, any alternatives or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the Surface controls which is meant for use on any Windows 7 touch device and is redistributable:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957352.aspx